# Django: How to use request.POST in a delete view

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I have a form sending data to a view via POST method. My problem is that I cant access the form's post data in the deleteview. After the song is deleted, I want the user to be sent back to the album-detail page to which the song belongs. My code is as shown below:

The form (inside album_detail.html):

```
<form action="{% url  'music:delete-song' pk=song.pk album_id=song.album_id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ song.album_id }}" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The urls.py:

```
#----
app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
   #----
   url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/detail/$', views.AlbumDetail.as_view(), name='album-detail'),
   url(r'^song/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.SongDelete.as_view(), name='delete-song'),
]
```

And finally the view:

```
class SongDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Song
    album_id = request.POST.get('album_id')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:album-detail', kwargs={'pk': album_id})
```

The album_id can not be set as above. How can I set the album_id to the post data album_id from the form, so that the user is sent back to the album-detail URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing your views `get_success_url` of course:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    album_id = self.request.POST.get('album_id')  # Do something else if it's missing?
    return reverse(  # no need for lazy here
        'music:album-detail', 
         kwargs={'pk': album_id}
    )
```

Comment: Just added self to request and it worked! I have not tested @cutteeth's answer but I found this one to be simple enough. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You Have to override `delete() and get_success_url()`

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    self.album = self.object.album # assuming that song have a foreignkey reference to album model 
    self.object.delete()
    success_url = self.get_success_url() 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)


def get_success_url(self):
    album = self.album    
    return reverse( 
        'music:album-detail', 
         kwargs={'pk': album.id}
        )
```

`success_url is obtained from get_success_url()` method and that method is called from `delete()`. Instead of calling reverse you can do something like

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return `/album/details/' + str(self.album.id)
```

To make it simpler. Or you can directory provide redirect_url in delete method.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    self.album = self.object.album # assuming that song have a foreignkey reference to album model 
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/album/details/' + str(self.album.id))
```

Refer to [this link](http://ccbv.co.uk) to get help on class based views